# Job distribution between nodes on HPC, instead of 1 CPU cores

Tags: c, hpc, pbs

I am using PBS, HPC to submit serially written C codes. I have to run suppose 5 codes in 5 different directories. when I select 1 node and 5 cores **select=1:ncpus=5**, and submits it with **./submit &**. It forks and runs all the 5 jobs. The moment I choose 5 node and 1 cores **select=5:ncpus=1**, and submits it with **./submit &**. Only 1 core of the first node runs all five jobs and rest 4 threads are free, speed decreased to 1/5.

My question is, Is it possible to fork the job between the nodes as well?
because when I select on HPC **select=1:ncpus=24** it gets to Que instead **select=4:ncpus=6** runs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using job arrays (using option `#PBS -t 1-5`) with I node and 1 cpu each. Then 5 independent jobs will start and your job will wait less in the queue.
Within your script you can use environment variable PBS_ARRAYID to identify the task and use it to set appropriate directory and start the appropriate C code. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -N yourjobname
#PBS -q yourqueue
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -t 1-5

./myprog-${PBS_ARRAYID}.c
```

This script will run 5 jobs and each of them will run programs with a name myprog-*.c where * is a number between 1 and 5.